# Is there a fast way to obtain filesystem capacity and usage by reading a single file?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, capacity

Is there a file system usage measurement in any /sys or /proc files?  Similarly for processes, besides diskstats is there a way to read a single number that reports total disk capacity consumed?

I ask because I need it for a low profile program and don't want the overhead of a system call - I'm aware of $df and $du, if necessary I'll read the source code for the answer but hoping if there is an alternative someone will know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need read code of the `df`, just run it under the `strace`.

So, seems like `df` uses the `statfs` syscall, not read something in `/proc` or `/sys`.

But reading of files happens with system calls, so you cannot avoid any overhead.